# regex sbustitute only specific hit sequence

Tags: python, regex, split, substitution

i have multiple string variations: `"gr_shoulder_r_tmp"`, `"r_shoulder_tmp"`
i need to substitute:

**"r_"** to **l_**, here:

```
"gr_shoulder_r_tmp" > "gr_shoulder_l_tmp"
"r_shoulder_tmp" > "l_shoulder_tmp"
```

in other words i need to subustitute 3rd coinsidence in frist example
and 1st in second example of stirngs

im started digging myself...
and came up into halfesolved result, which bore one more interesting question:

> **a) Find index of right hit**

`[i for i, x in enumerate(re.findall("(.?)(r_)", "gr_shoulder_r_tmp")) if filter(None, x).__len__() == 1]`
which gives me `indx = 2`

> *?) how to use that hit index :[*

while wrote this i found straight simple solution..

> **b) split by underscore, replace standalone letter, and join back**

```
findtag = "r"
newtag = "l"
itemA = "gr_shoulder_r_tmp"
itemB = "r_shoulderr_tmp"
spl_str = itemA.split("_")
hit = spl_str.index(findtag)
spl_str[hit] = newtag
new_item = "_".join(spl_str)
```

both `itemA`,`itemB` gives me what i need.. but im not happy of it, too heavy and so rough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex will do this job.

```
re.sub(r'(?<![a-zA-Z])r_', 'l_', s)
```

`(?<![a-zA-Z])` negative lookbehind which asserts that the match would be preceeded by any but not a letter.

**Example:**

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<![a-zA-Z])r_', 'l_',"gr_shoulder_r_tmp")
'gr_shoulder_l_tmp'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<![a-zA-Z])r_', 'l_',"r_shoulder_tmp")
'l_shoulder_tmp'
```

Comment: great! ty alot Avinash Raj. Can you plz explain what that does `(?<!) `

Comment: ive got that replaced too if i have `gr_shoulderr_r_tmp` -rr_ ... oh my bad.. i forgot to remove ^(cap) from letter pattens

Comment: That's called a negative look behind assertion, as you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). It's important that you understand it, because you may need to adjust the condition.